# Target multiple directories

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to create a target which matches multiple directories, but no files. Is there any way to flag the target explicitly as being a directory?

For example:

```
output/%:
    mkdir -p $@
```

matches files as well, which is definitely not something I want.

Basically, I have many variables which contain directory names which need to be created if they don't exist, and the best way to do that, as far as I've found is this:

```
all: directories other_stuff

directories: $(dir1) $(dir2) ...

$(dir1):
    mkdir -p $@
$(dir2):
    mkdir -p $@
...
```

So, I'm OK with repeating the directory variables as dependencies for the `directories` target, but creating targets for each directory I add seems overkill and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
DIR_LIST = $(dir1) $(dir2) $(dir3)

.PHONY: all
all: directories other_stuff

.PHONY: directories  # Note: you should be marking this as phony
directories: $(DIR_LIST)

$(DIR_LIST):
    mkdir -p $@
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets.

Comment: Oh, that's nice :) Thanks a million!

Comment: Do you also know, by any chance, how to create a target that matches any object file inside a directory? This does not seem to work: `output/%.o:`

Comment: Relying on the order in which prerequisites are checked is a bad practice since it may not work as expected on parallel builds (`make -jN`).

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov Noted. Thanks. Anyway, I managed to figure out how the % wildcard works. Writing Makefiles is hard...